# Unable to ssh into database with heidisql

Tags: ssh, forge, heidisql

Configuration I am using:

```
Network type : SSH Tunnel
Hostname : 127.0.0.1
User : *Database Username*
Password : *Database Password*

SSH Host : Server IP
Port : 22
Username : *Username*
Private key file : .ssh/id_rsa
```

Error I am getting:

```
PLink exited unexpected. Command line was: pling.exe -ssh forge@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx -P 22 -i "C:\Users\Ruben\.ssh\id_rsa" -N -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306
```

Can ssh with no problem on my console. So the ssh key is properly set up. What am I missing here?

**edit**: exact same configuration works find in MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem comes from the fact that HeidiSQL only supports putty for ssh tunnels and Putty doesn't support OpenSSH.

So, you have to download puttygen.exe. Run it. Go to conversion and save as private key. You can then use that private key to connect on HeidiSQL.

You can find some more information [here](https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=17853)

Comment: I am using a private key already, but i am unable to login and still gets this error

Comment: Same here. I already use a private key and I still get this error. Any news on that @iiiml0sto1 ?